# translation from python to R (recursive function)

Tags: python, r, recursion

I have some code in python which I'm trying to translate into R.  It is a recursive function, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something about how recursive calls work in either R or python.

Values for a run example:

```
k = 2
v = 1
ln_lambda = 1.1
ln_theta = .25
```

Here's the python code:

```py
import numpy as np
def lognormal_cascade(k, v, ln_lambda, ln_theta):
    
    k = k - 1
    
    m0 = np.random.lognormal(ln_lambda,ln_theta)
    m1 = np.random.lognormal(ln_lambda,ln_theta)
    M = [m0, m1]
    
    if (k >= 0):
        d=[0 for x in range(0,2)]
        for i in range(0,2):
            d[i] = lognormal_cascade(k, (M[i]*v), ln_lambda, ln_theta)
        v = d
    
    return v
```

Here's my attempt at a translation into R:

```
lognormal_cascade <- function(k, v, ln_lambda, ln_theta) {
      k = k - 1
      m0 = rlnorm(1, meanlog = ln_lambda, sdlog = ln_theta)
      m1 = rlnorm(1, meanlog = ln_lambda, sdlog = ln_theta)
      M = c(m0, m1)
      
      if (k >= 0) {
        d = rep(0, 2)
        for (i in c(1, 2)) {
          d[i] = lognormal_cascade(k, (M[i] * v), ln_lambda, ln_theta)
        }
        v = d
      }
      return (v)  
    }
```

I'm not sure how the call in python works: d[i] = lognormal_cascade(k, (M[i]*v), ln_lambda, ln_theta)  for after the first loop, the v is a list of values.  But the code works in python somehow; giving back a list of lists, which can be flattened easily.  In R, there is a warning given, and then it gives back (what I assume is the first value).

```
Warning message: In d[i] = lognormal_cascade(k, (M[i] * v), ln_lambda, ln_theta) :   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Any help would be appreciated to understand how the python recursive call works, and how I could port to R.

Comment: We don't have any code to run. You won't get that warning from what you showed us.  You need to post a reproducible example.  Making it minimal is also requested:  drop stuff from your Python version and from the R version until they match, then gradually add things back until they don't.

Comment: Will keep this in mind for next time.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for editing your question to include the required information. Some minor tweaks to your R code should solve your problem:

```py
cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

def lognormal_cascade(k, v,ln_lambda, ln_theta):
    k = k - 1
    m0 = np.random.lognormal(ln_lambda,ln_theta)
    m1 = np.random.lognormal(ln_lambda,ln_theta)
    M = [m0, m1]

    if (k >= 0):
        d=[0 for x in range(0,2)]
        for i in range(0,2):
            d[i] = lognormal_cascade(k, (M[i]*v), ln_lambda, ln_theta)
        v = d

    return v

print(lognormal_cascade(2, 1, 1.1, 0.25))

./test.py
[[10.29707908019117, 11.462432976881722], [15.559573184554486, 11.159420526353305]]
```

```r
lognormal_cascade <- function(k, v, ln_lambda, ln_theta) {
  k = k - 1
  m0 = rlnorm(1, meanlog = ln_lambda, sdlog = ln_theta)
  m1 = rlnorm(1, meanlog = ln_lambda, sdlog = ln_theta)
  M = c(m0, m1)
  
  if (k >= 0) {
    d = list()  # create a list to store the results
    for (i in c(1, 2)) {
      d[[i]] = lognormal_cascade(k, (M[i] * v), ln_lambda, ln_theta) # use "[[" instead of "["
    }
    v = d
  }
  return (v)  
}

result <- lognormal_cascade(k = 2, v = 1, ln_lambda = 1.1, ln_theta = 0.25)
result
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 13.10512
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 8.760005
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 11.42201
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 13.30253

unlist(result)
#> [1] 13.105119  8.760005 11.422010 13.302525
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

NB. there's no seed in either language so you get different random numbers, and subsequently different results, each time you run the function. I'm guessing that's by design, but if not please leave a comment below.

Comment: Thanks!  You are correct, these are to provide random numbers from the random log normal draws, so I wouldn't expect them to match, just in the length or dimension.

Looks like it's possible to call the unlist inside the function if desired as well:

v = unlist(d)   // replacing    v=d